# startsWith String method does not seem to be working properly

Tags: java, string, startswith

I have a Java program that reads from an input file with inputStream and writes to an output file with outputStream. The file has comment lines that start with the pound sign "#" and also contains blank lines. I am trying to have Scanner skip over these lines to get to the actual information. I can't hard code the amount of lines to skip because the input file could change. Here is the section of code I have that I thought would accomplish what I need:

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        if (!(line.startsWith("#")) || !(line.isEmpty())) {
            outputStream.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with the logic? I thought with this code only the lines that are not blank or do not start with a pound sign would be written to my output file, but instead the entire input file is written to the output file, comment lines and blank lines included. My guess is that I do not quite understand how the startsWith method works properly. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you for reading!

**EDIT**

Here is where inputStream is defined:

```
Scanner inputStream = null;
try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File TripPlanner4_Vehicles.txt was not found");
        System.out.println("or could not be opened.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Also here is the beginning of the input file which is a text file:

```
# Ignore blank lines and comment lines (begins with pound sign '#')

# The vertical bar '|' is used as the field delimiter within each vehicle record

# Table of Vehicle Records
#   Column headings:
#     Type|Make|Model|Feature(s)|Engine Size (liters)|# Cyl|Fuel Type|Tank Size     (gallons)|City MPG|Hwy MPG|Towing?

Car|Chevrolet|Camaro||3.60|6|Unleaded|5.0|19|30|
Car|Chevrolet|Cruze||1.80|4|Unleaded|4.0|22|35|
Car|Chevrolet|Sonic||1.80|4|Unleaded|4.0|25|35|
```

**EDIT 2**

I have come up with an approach that accomplishes what I need, although this might only work for the input file I am working with:

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.useDelimiter("|").nextLine();
        if (!line.contains("#") && (line.length() > 1)) { 
            outputStream.println(line);
        }
    }
```

This approach does skip lines that have "#" in them or blank lines, however if a line were to contain "#" anywhere in the line it would be skipped. My input file only puts these at the beginning of lines and are used no where else, so it works for my case. If anyone has a more dynamic solution, they are welcome to share. Hope this helps others with a similar situation. Thank you to all who replied and took the time to help!

Comment: Before you assume `.startsWith("#")` isn't working, I'd recommend testing it independently rather than in that `if` statement as it is...

Comment: Try reading the if statement out loud as in "if this line starts with # OR the line is not empty" and you can see where the problem lies.

Comment: I read that when implementing the starsWith method with the String ("") is would return true, so technically every line starts with this empty String, how would I go about skipping this empty String?

Answer (score 4):

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        if (!(line.startsWith("#")) && !(line.isEmpty())) {
            outputStream.println(line);
        }
}
```

Wrong operators. More clear:

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();
        if (!(line.startsWith("#") || line.isEmpty())) {
            outputStream.println(line);
        }
}
```

This reads as if it's English and won't get you any possible mistakes.

Comment: This approach is still printing the entire input file to the output file. Have you seen other approaches for doing this, maybe using different methods from the String class?

Comment: @user3015501: nothing that comes to mind. This should just work though, can you share a working code sample?

Comment: I tried just implementing the code "String line = inputStream.nextLine(); outputStream.println(line.startsWith("#");" and it printed false, so according the the method, no lines start with the "#" symbol. I can't explain this though.

Comment: @user3015501: show where you define the inputstream, please. Could you also show a sample inputfile?

Comment: I added what I thought would help, hopefully it adds more insight into the whole thing.

Comment: Are you saying it only displayed `false` once? Or did it display that for every line?

Comment: It prints 'false' for every line in the file

Comment: You'll have to go trough it with the debugger to see where it's going wrong. Put a breakpoint in your loop and check the value of `line` each time.

Comment: Looking through the debugger, line first gets initialized with the string starting with "ˇ˛#" so the startsWith method was not checking for these special characters "ˇ˛" which don't appear when looking at the input file with a text editor, so I'm assuming they are special characters used by the system. but every other line actually begins with just "#" which startsWith should catch, but it does not, so I'm not sure what it thinks line starts with.

Answer (score 3):

Use `&&` instead of `||`.  You want lines that are not empty and also do not start with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

Print if it doesn't start with `#` OR if it isn't empty should have an AND there.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 boolean startsWith= line.indexOf('#')==1;
```